# Nested UpdatePanel - Update Parent UpdatePanel without updating the Child UpdatePanels?

Tags: asp.net-ajax

Is there a way to update only the parent UpdatePanel without updating the child UpdatePanel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe there is a complicated way to do that that I'm not aware of. So far I know this is NOT possible.

http://www.asp.net/(S(ywiyuluxr3qb2dfva1z5lgeg))/learn/Ajax/tutorial-02-cs.aspx

> Note that when UpdatePanel controls are nested, when the UpdateMode is set to Conditional, if 
>   the child UpdatePanel is triggered, but the parent is not, then only the child UpdatePanel will refresh. However, if the parent UpdatePanel is refreshed, then the child UpdatePanel will also be refreshed.

Answer (score -1):

Set your Child UpdatePanels to UpdateMode=Conditional